# Split up .vimrc, where to put what?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I've go a bunch of filetype dependent `autocommands` in my `.vimrc`, some of which are syntax related.

I'd like to put these in separate file throughout my `.vim/` tree, eg. some tex syntax would go in `.vim/syntax/tex.vim` but when I do this, `vim` doesn't pick up on them anymore.

I'm guessing that the files aren't read in automatically (as I first expected). What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put the autocommands in those separate files as autocommands? That is, does your `~/.vim/syntax/tex.vim` contain lines like this,

```
au FileType tex set expandtab
```

or this,

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex set expandtab
```

If so, that's wrong. Vim sources the files in the ftplugin, syntax and indent directories when a file of the file type corresponding to the name of the plugin is opened. If the plugin contains autocommands, those autocommands will be read and executed but the command portion won't be executed until the *next* time the triggering event occurs.

If you want to make some filetype-dependent setting, put a command like this in the ftplugin for that file type.

```
setlocal expandtab
```

Don't put it in an autocommand and do use `setlocal` rather than just `set` so that the setting will apply to the buffer containing that file type and not apply to all your Vim buffers.

See

```
:help 43.1
:help 41.11
```

**Edit**

I forgot to answer another part of the question. Vim has three types of filetype-dependent plugins that go in three different subdirectories of ~/.vim: ftplugin, syntax and indent. The indent subdirectory is intended for plugins that affect the indentation of specific file types. The syntax subdirectory is intended for plugins that affect syntax coloring. The ftplugin is intended for plugins that affect behavioral settings such as textwidth, mappings, abbreviations and such.

Comment: I put stuff in it like this `syntax match ...` no autocommand, yet it seems as if `vim` ignores this in `~/.vim/syntax/tex.vim`

Comment: @romeovs: Things to try: `:set ft?` should show "filetype=tex"; `:set rtp?` should show a comma-separated list of directories which includes "~/.vim"; `:scriptnames` should show a list of all the plugins that Vim has sourced since starting up and if you're editing a TeX or LaTeX file, should show that it looked for plugins with the name "tex.vim".